# When I mention height and width of element as 100% it renders in different browsers with different height in pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on application to capture the Dom of the webpage that are rendered in different browsers. I am getting the json of the Height and width top and left position of the element in browser. I figured out there is difference in height and width depends upon the browsers toolbars etc.. when i mentioned the css of html, body as 100%.

eg : chrome

```
{
  "elementName": "BODY",
  "xpath": "/html/body",
  "top": 0,
  "left": 0,
  "width": 1350,
  "height": 100,
  "absX": 8,
  "absY": 18
}

eg : Firefox 

  {
    "elementName": "BODY",
    "xpath": "/html/body",
    "top": 0,
    "left": 0,
    "width": 1350,
    "height": 120,
    "absX": 8,
    "absY": 18
 }
```

Here you can see that height of body is more by 20px in firefox compared to chrome.
so my question is how to make the width and height same for all the browsers or how to ignore the height difference.

Comment: The height of `window` depends on the size of the browser window, diffrent menus, tools, borders, possible status lines etc. vary browser by browser.

Comment: try to use 100vh, not %

Answer (score 1):

> **I think this is because different browsers have different default**
>   **line-heights, so if you set your element to a specific line-height,**
>   **it will look the same on all browsers.**

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the method you use to calculate `height` of the `element`, like I used `getBoundingClientRect().height` ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/xnnnaju2/3/)) to get the exact `height` of the element `div`, this `height` is shown same in all major browsers.

Also, [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/xnnnaju2/5/) in which

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

which also shows the same `height` in all browsers.